# transform scheme interpreter to C

Tags: c, scheme, racket, transformation, interpreter

So I am currently working on a project that requires me to convert my interpreter from scheme to C.

Below is the interpreter I have now after the first step which is "add the expr define-union to your file, change the match-expression in value-of-cps to instead be a union-case-expression":

```
(define-union expr
  (const cexp)
  (var n)
  (if test conseq alt)
  (mult nexp1 nexp2)
  (sub1 nexp)
  (zero nexp)
  (letcc body)
  (throw kexp vexp)
  (let exp body)                  
  (lambda body)
  (app rator rand))

(define-label value-of-cps
  (lambda (expr env k)
     (union-case k expr
       [(var n) (apply-env env n k)]
       [(const cexp) (k cexp)]
       [(mult nexp1 nexp2) (value-of-cps nexp1 env (lambda (x) (value-of-cps nexp2 env (lambda (x^) (k (* x x^))))))]
       [(sub1 nexp) (value-of-cps nexp env (lambda (x) (k (sub1 x))))]
       [(zero nexp) (value-of-cps nexp env (lambda (x) (k (zero? x))))]
       [(if test conseq alt) (value-of-cps test env (lambda (x) (if x (value-of-cps conseq env k) (value-of-cps alt env k))))]
       [(letcc body) (value-of-cps body (extend-env k env) k)]
       [(throw kexp vexp) (value-of-cps kexp env (lambda (x) (value-of-cps vexp env (lambda (x^) (x x^)))))]
       [(let exp body) (value-of-cps exp env (lambda (x) (value-of-cps body (extend-env x env) k)))]            
       [(lambda body)  (k (make-closure body env))]
       [(app rator rand) (value-of-cps rator env (lambda (x) (value-of-cps rand env (lambda (x^) (apply-closure x x^ k)))))])))
```

although, When I try to run this main function with my interpreter:

```
define main 
  (lambda ()
    (value-of-cps 
     (expr_let 
      (expr_lambda
       (expr_lambda 
        (expr_if
         (expr_zero (expr_var 0))
          (expr_const 1)
           (expr_mult (expr_var 0) (expr_app (expr_app (expr_var 1) (expr_var 1)) (expr_sub1 (expr_var 0)))))))
            (expr_mult
             (expr_letcc
              (expr_app
               (expr_app (expr_var 1) (expr_var 1))
                (expr_throw (expr_var 0) (expr_app (expr_app (expr_var 1) (expr_var 1)) (expr_const 4)))))
       (expr_const 5)))
     (empty-env)
     (empty-k))))
```

I get an error saying that:

value-of-cps: arity mismatch;
 the expected number of arguments does not match the given number
  expected: 0
  given: 3
  arguments...:

but my interpreter does take 3 arguments.... Please help!! Thank you!

Comment: You're using a lot of non-standard library hardware. For instance: what is define-label? What is define-union? BTW, this looks like fun. Whose curriculum is this.... Jay McCarthy's?

Comment: What does this have to do with converting to C?

Comment: please add definitions for empty-env & empty-k